# How to align an image in a xe:inputRichText (or HTML pass-through)?

Tags: xpages

I'm using the Domino 8.5.3 <xe:inputRichText>  control for end-users to add web content.  The control has the basic feature to add an image, but no "align" settings to float text around the image (ex.  <img align="right"> ), which is so common with basic HTML.

One work-around tried is to use a 2-column table, which works, but not as well (especially, when re-sizing the window).

Any ideas for a work-around?  Is there anything similar to 'Pass-thru HTML' in a inputRichText control?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to set toolbar style to large and then simply switch to HTML source (the last but one button) and change it whatever You like:

http://www-10.lotus.com/ldd/ddwiki.nsf/dx/CKEditor_in_XPages_in_NotesDomino_8.5.2